# CypressIO testing Framework - capture requests data

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend, cypress

I make a post request via cy.request. The post internally redirects to another site along with a fragment (for eg: http://xyz redirects to http://www.lll.com/#fragData=1). I would like to capture the value of fragData.

From documentation cy.request only yields a response.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 4):

I found a useful setting to resolve this - followRedirect can be set to false to capture the 302 and fragment data.

Documentation link:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Options

Eg:

```
cy.request({
  url: '/dashboard',
  followRedirect: false // turn off following redirects
})
  .then((resp) => {
    // redirect status code is 302
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(302)
    expect(resp.redirectedToUrl).to.eq('http://localhost:8082/unauthorized')
  })
```